# Issues with trigger not inserting data on another database

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I have a trigger which updates a table in another database. I have checked the select statement and it does return the correct values but it just won't update the target table with anything at all.

```
USE [Dashboard]
GO
/****** Object:  Trigger [dbo].[UpdateUser]    Script Date: 13/11/2014 12:15:04 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author:      <Author,,Name>
-- Create date: <Create Date,,>
-- Description: <Description,,>
-- =============================================
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[UpdateUser]
   ON  [dbo].[Dashboard]
   FOR INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;


    INSERT INTO Portal.dbo.Dashboards
            (Company, UserID, DashboardID)
    SELECT  LEFT(EA.roleOrUser,CHARINDEX(',',EA.roleOrUser)-1), -- Company - nvarchar(250)
             RIGHT(EA.roleOrUser,CHARINDEX(',',EA.roleOrUser)-4), -- UserID - int
             i.id  -- DashboardID - int

    FROM Inserted i
    INNER JOIN dbo.EntityAuth EA
    ON i.id = EA.entityid 


END
```

Comment: I don't see anything wrong in the code. Can you turn NOCOUNT on? That would at least let you see the rowcounts while you are debugging this.

Comment: Could it be that the user-login doesn't have permission to INSERT on Portal db?

Comment: Another you could do is to add a select statement in your trigger so you can at runtime what the output of your select statement is.

Comment: It's almost always a better idea to introduce some decoupling here (queue table, service broker, etc) so that the original transaction can complete without being at the mercy of what's happening in another database

Comment: @SeanLange The problem is that the source table is populated from an application of which I don't have the source code, so I'm a little lost for debugging options.

Comment: I meant to comment out SET NOCOUNT ON

Comment: Might be you need to explicitly cast the UserID as an int.

Comment: @TabAlleman I tried it and still nothing inserted.

Comment: @SeanLange I am getting 0 rows updated and 1 row updated. It suggests the trigger is running before the insert?

Comment: As a test, change the trigger to SELECT .... INTO NewTestTable.  Then look at the data that is being inserted, and try to run the insert query based on that table.

Comment: @connersz: Are both databases on the same servers?

Comment: @PareshJ Yes the same server.

Comment: @LeeG I tried to do this but it kept saying no column was specified on the from statement.

Comment: That is because you need to provide an alias that select into will use as column names.

Comment: check if there is 'trigger before' on Portal.dbo.Dashboards...

Comment: @DudiKonfino There are no other triggers on the entire database.

Answer (score 0):

Check user permissions in the target database.  Triggers fire within the context of the user that initiated the trigger.

Comment: At the moment it is ran using dbo